# How do i convert a React-Native-Fetch-Blob Blob into a base64/Image

Tags: react-native, react-native-fetch-blob

I am trying to store images in Firebase.Storage using React-Native-Fetch-Blob and i have finally gotten something into storage but the file in storage is now full nonsense/compressed data which i can't really use for anything.

how do I turn the blob back into BASE64 or image so that I can use the image in my application

`

```
upLoadImage(image, mime = 'application/octet-stream') {
    const imageRef = firebase.storage().ref('images').child('image_001')
    let uploadBlob = null
    console.log('phase 2');
    Blob.build(image, {
        type: `${mime};BASE64`
    }).then((blob) => {
        console.log(imageRef.toString());
        uploadBlob = blob
        imageRef.put(blob, {
            contentType: mime
        })
        console.log('phase 2');
        console.log(imageRef.toString());
        console.log(imageRef.getDownloadURL());
        imageRef.getDownloadURL()
    }).catch((error) => {
        console.log(error.toString());
    })
}
```

`

The code is based upon this project https://github.com/dailydrip/react-native-firebase-storage/blob/master/src/App.js#L43-L69

Answer (score 0):

Below code converts URL to base64 image

```
   RNFetchBlob.fetch("GET", "ImageURL").then(resp => {
   base64image.push("data:image/png;base64," + resp.data);              
        console.log(base64image);   // -> your base64 image       
   });
```